# Declaring multiple pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to define multiple pointers from the argv array, and am unsuccessful in doing so.

```c
char *val1, *val2, *val3, *val4 = argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4];
```

```
file.c: In function 'valid_args':
file.c:108:60: error: conflicting types for 'argv'
         char *val1, *val2, *val3 = argv[1], argv[2], argv[3];
                                                            ^
file.c:108:51: note: previous declaration of 'argv' was here
         char *val1, *val2, *val3 = argv[1], argv[2], argv[3];
                                                   ^
file.c:127:60: error: conflicting types for 'argv'
         char *val1, *val2, *val3 = argv[1], argv[2], argv[3];
                                                            ^
file.c:127:51: note: previous declaration of 'argv' was here
         char *val1, *val2, *val3 = argv[1], argv[2], argv[3];
                                                   ^
file.c:128:24: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
         char *val4 = argv[4];
```

Comment: Simple syntax error, try `char *val1 = argv[1], *val2 = argv[2] ...` OTOH `char *val1; val1 = argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4];` is valid syntax but rather pointless.

Comment: ^^^ That would solve the immediate issue, but may I ask why aren't you using the `argv` array directly? Also, are you confident that, say, `argv[4]` actually exists?

Comment: Yep, have done other validation and know that argv contains exactly 4 elements. Thanks @WeatherVane for the response tho. Do you mind posting it as a response so I can mark it as the accepted answer? Would love to help someone who stumbles upon it in the future

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your code.

Better way to do that:

```
char *var1, *var2, *var3, *var4;
var1 = argv[1];
var2 = argv[2];
var3 = argv[3];
var4 = argv[4];
```

It's also more readable.

Answer (score 0):

As @WeatherVane has suggested, instead of writing:

```
char *val1, *val2, *val3, *val4 = argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4];
```

You should instead write:

```
char *val1 = argv[1], *val2 = argv[2], *val3 = argv[3], *val4 = argv[4];
```